# Is it possible to run Gatsby side-by-side with a regular React single page application?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, gatsby

The particular use case I'm looking at is running a single page application at the root path `/` of a domain, and having a statically rendered blog at `/blog`.

I've already checked out the advice at https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/path-prefix/, however I'm not entirely sure how this would interact with the React app running at `/`

Is there a way to get React Router in the React app to support handing over to Gatsby?

Comment: You could just host them separately and do this with url rewrites in nginx or another http server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gatsby is just React so yes :-)

Build your SPA & blog both with Gatsby. Put the entry to your SPA at `src/pages/index.js` and it'll be served at `/`.

If you need client-only routes, you can set those up like this: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/creating-and-modifying-pages/#creating-client-only-routes

Gatsby is basically CRA with some additional features to make it easy to build websites.